# Weird cofinality behavior without choice?

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

I vaguely recall the following result, but can't find it or prove it on my own; I'd like to check if it, or something similar to it, is actually true. My memory is that the proof is rather hard, FWIW.

> **Vague memory**: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are linear orders $X,Y$ such that
>
> 1. every cofinal subset of $X$ is in (non-order-preserving) bijection with some cofinal subset of $Y$ and every cofinal subset of $Y$ is in (non-order-preserving) bijection with some cofinal subset of $X$, but
> 2. there is no linear order $Z$ which cofinally embeds into both $X$ and $Y$.

Basically, in the absence of choice the class of *(Scott) cardinalities of* cofinal subsets of a linear order can fail to determine the class of *ordertypes of* cofinal subsets of that linear order, in an extremely strong way: two linear orders can have identical "coarse cofinality behaviors" but completely disjoint "fine cofinality behaviors." One immediate observation is that neither $X$ and $Y$ can have a well-ordered cofinal subset, but beyond that not much is clear to me.

Comment: Well, in particular $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality. So it's really two linear orders on the same sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but I don't see a way to get much from that.

Comment: Well, just in case someone wants to try and tackle that, it's a small observation that might helpful.